# Volley NetworkImageView being resized after loading

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I have a ListView where I display an Instagram-like feed with thumbnails and screen-filling pictures.
I use a Volley NetworkImageView for both the profile thumbnail and main picture and I have placeholders that are exactly the same size as the images downloaded from the server.

thumbnail: 128x128
image: 612x612

My problem is that after the image are loaded, they don't fill the screen anymore, it seems that volley is resizing them which results in abrupt change of layout. Also the layout of the thumbnail is changing slightly (padding) (see screenshots).

Any Idea of what might be wrong and can I do to fix this?

**EDIT** It seems that the layout is forcing the image to be smaller once it is loaded, if I set `android:scaleType:centerCrop`, the image takes full width but is cropped in height. How can I force the image to satisfy the constraint full width while keeping its height?

[image]

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip" >

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:src="@drawable/holder_spot_thumbnail" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" ></TextView>



    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/holder_feed_image" 
        android:padding="6dip"/>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try setting exact value like 200dip for layout_width and layout_height

Comment: then the size stays the same but then I have to manually adjust the image to the screen width, I was hopping for a solution i the xml like match_parent... Actually it did work before and then something changed and I can't get it to work again so i'm trying to understand...

Comment: you're saying the images that are being sent from the server are always the correct size? Try giving both NetworkImageViews a defaultResourceId asset which is also in the correct size, then use wrap content on both dimensions. This way the image views will be properly measured before the image request is sent, and should adjust properly when the bitmap arrives.